# Java Deep copy with inheritance and certain restrictions

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, copy

First off I have the following restrictions

1. 'Do NOT attempt to explicitly find the exact type of the objects being copied,'
2. 'do NOT attempt to find the object type inside the copy constructors'
3. 'and Do NOT use clone().'

Keep in mind this is only a programming 2 class, we aren't allowed to use things like Serialization.

Say I have an Address Object

```
public class Address {
    
    protected String validFrom;
    protected String validTo;
...
    public Address getAddress() {
        return this;
    }
...
```

Then I have another object which inherits from Address, 
also has a copy constructor which also makes a new Address to be used

```
public class EmailAddress extends Address {

    protected String userName;
    protected String domainName;
    protected String tld;
...
    public EmailAddress(EmailAddress other) {
        this(other.userName, other.domainName, other.tld, new Address(other.getAddress()));
    }
...
```

Then I use this function to copy the addresses

```
    public static Address[] copyAddresses(Address[] addresses) {
        Address[] copyAddresse = new Address[addresses.length];
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
            copyAddresse[i] = new Address(addresses[i]);
        }
        
        return copyAddresse;
    }
```

With the given requirements preforming a deep copy would be impossible correct? my reasoning comes from the fact that we are only able to create a new Address we loose the additional information from the Email class?

Comment: Can you change the `Address` and `EmailAddress` classes?

Comment: Yeah I could change them

Comment: Ah then I think the point here is to use polymorphism. Create a `deepCopy` method in `Address`, and override it in `EmailAddress`. Since this is probably homework I will only tell you that much.

Comment: in the assignment it says:
Your copy of the objects will automatically depend on the copy constructors of the different listed classes.

so we are forced to use the copy constructor, Thanks for the creative solution if it wasn't dependent on the copy constructor it would of been great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'do NOT attempt to find the object type inside the copy constructors'

What is that supposed to mean?

If you take as given: *The object in question is of a type which has the property that it has a public copy constructor*, which is definitely not true for all types, and plays havoc with ad-hoc created anonymous inner classes and the like, you *can* do this:

```
Class<?> objType = obj.getClass();
Constructor<?> ctr = objType.getConstructor(objType.class);
return ctr.newInstance(obj);
```

will get the job done. I can't make heads or tails of your requirement - but if the above is 'not acceptable according to the rules', then, no, it is indeed impossible.

Comment: When I asked the person who created the question he responded with "While copying the elements of the address array, you must not check the type explicitly."

Comment: Well, this doesn't check the type explicitly, but it will fail unless that copy constructor exists, and is of the exact right type (takes 1 argument of the same type as itself).

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss this note?

> Display the contents of both arrays, then add some comments indicating whether or not the copying is correct. If not; you need to explain why it has not been successful or as you might have expected.

Maybe it's impossible with those restrictions, just explain why they're different.